# How to avoid overlapping objects in image based on known object coordinates in image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

in the following, I will describe my problem as easy as possible based on a schematic representation. I have an image with some objects, for example existing black stars. Furthermore, I know the coordinates of those black stars. I wrote a code which copy yellow circles in the image based on randomly generated x and y-coordinates. But sometimes the yellow circles and black stars overlapping. I want to avoid this. My idea is to this based on the known coordinates. If I know the (x1,y1;x2,y2) position of the objects, then I can look if there are overlapping pixel coordinates within the range of (x1,y1;x2,y2) of the particular object.
My problem is that I don't know how to extract the pixel coordinates in a particular range. Can anybody give me a hint?[image: schematic representation]

Comment: just make sure the bounding boxes don't overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the coordinates of the polygon, you can check whether there are any intersections using the [shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html) library

```py
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

poly1 = Polygon([
  (obj1_x1, obj1_y1), (obj1_x1, obj1_y2), 
  (obj1_x2, obj1_y1), (obj1_x2, obj1_y2)])
poly2 = Polygon([
  (obj2_x1, obj2_y1), (obj2_x1, obj2_y2), 
  (obj2_x2, obj2_y1), (obj2_x2, obj2_y2)])
print(poly1.intersects(poly2))
```